# I'm getting a error even though i added @babel/present-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm having some issues with babel, I alredy added babel/present-react, but error remains

**Error** -> (npx babel src/index.js --out-file dist/bundle.js)

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to 
the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

**Code that i'm trying to convert**

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "01-github-explore",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5"
  }
}
```

**babel.config**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ]
}
```

When I add babel/present-react the following show up

```
**npm add @babel/preset-react **  

up to date, audited 207 packages in 2s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

What i'm doing wrong?

I tried put the following code, but still nothing

```
"@babel/preset-react",
    {
      "pragma": "dom", // default pragma is React.createElement (only in classic runtime)
      "pragmaFrag": "DomFrag", // default is React.Fragment (only in classic runtime)
      "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
      "runtime": "classic" // defaults to classic
      // "importSource": "custom-jsx-library" // defaults to react (only in automatic runtime)
    }
```

It was on babel website

Comment: Can't reproduce it.